# javascript, jquery animate() function problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Here is a photo link: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qvrhniSiDARVdLAK7

I have a question. If i want to use jQuery animate() function stuff must be 'position: relative' ? Because when it's position relative stuff goes on top of fixed menu...

Comment: What is "stuff"?

Comment: Stuff here means my website header text :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add z-index in css like 'z-index: 10000' so it goes on top of everythin.